# javascript - minio client with ipv6

Tags: javascript, ipv6, minio, fly

I want to upload an image to a Minio server, both the app and the server in the same IPv6 Network. Fetching the images with `fetch()` works awesome, but when I want to connect with `Minio.Client`, the `invalid endpoint` error throws.

This is my configuration:

```js
        const minioClient = new Minio.Client({
            endPoint: (env.MINIO_ENDPOINT as string),
            useSSL: false,
            accessKey: env.MINIO_USER as string,
            secretKey: env.MINIO_SECRET as string,
        })
```

where the `MINIO_ENDPOINT` is `[fdaa:0:e9af:0:1::8]`, and the server listens on port `80`

This works locally when the endpoint is `localhost`, both user and password works fine on test.